# Read property of document class of FLA file using jsfl script

Tags: jsfl, flash-cs5.5

I create a script (document class) and attack into a FLA file.

[Document class here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWVo7.png).

```
public dynamic class MainClass extends MovieClip
{
    public var xPos:int;
    public var yPos:int;
}
```

Now, I run a jsfl script to read value of xPos & yPos of document class. But It does not work:

```
var obj = new MainClass();
fl.trace(obj.xPos+":"+obj.yPos); // edited
```

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `ActionScript` classes aren't present in JSFL. The JS in JSFL stands for `JavaScript`, which is a different language from `ActionScript`.

Second, in order to access an objects properties (in either AS or JS) you need to use a reference to the object itself.

```
var obj = new MyKlass();
fl.trace(obj.xPos+":"+obj.yPos);
```

Comment: So, the aswner for my question is impossible.
Thanks.